# Update CloudFormation stack with updated file in Init

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

In my CloudFormation stack I have AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration, and within that I have AWS::CloudFormation::Init with various packages, files, etc.

One of my files in Init is a .jar that I upload to S3, which the stack grabs. I'd like to make changes to and reupload the .jar, and have the stack update with this new .jar without having to delete and recreate the stack. Can this be done?

I've come across documentation on cfn-hup, but I'm not sure how to specify that the stack update with changes to the files within Init - maybe in the path for the hooks configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the stack with the new file reference to the S3 jar file. No need to delete the stack. An update will create a new launch configuration with the new file reference.

Then re-launch your instances as needed.  Then each instance will have the new jar file.

Comment: Thanks!! When you say update the stack, do you mean editing the template with the new S3 path to the .jar file (and does that mean the .jar file name will have to be modified for a change in the template to be detected)?

Comment: Yes I would use a new name to keep clear. But really if you had the same name, then all you need to do is relaunch instances via ASG to replace them.  Its up to you if you think add a version name to the file is useful.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how exactly do you relaunch instances? Do you mean just rebooting them in the EC2 dashboard?

Comment: Stop or terminate current instances.. This will cause new instances to be relaunched.